# Why can't the compiler deduce auto template parameter unless I add const?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I recently had problem with code like this:

```
constexpr auto lambda = []{};

template<auto& l>
struct Lambda {};

template<auto& l>
void test(Lambda<l>) {}

int main() {
    test(Lambda<lambda>{});
}
```

Both clang and GCC tells that it can't deduce `l`.

However, if I add const there:

```
//   ----v
template<const auto& l>
void test(Lambda<l>) {}
```

Then everything works with clang. GCC still fails. What's happening here? Can it not deduce the `const` itself? Is this a GCC bug for it to not deducing `l` in both cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this a GCC bug for it to not deducing l in both cases?

It is a bug, and for Clang too. For a placeholder type non-type argument, [[temp.arg.nontype]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype#1) says:

> If the type of a template-parameter contains a placeholder type, **the
>   deduced parameter type is determined from the type of the
>   template-argument by placeholder type deduction**. If a deduced
>   parameter type is not permitted for a template-parameter declaration
>   ([temp.param]), the program is ill-formed.

The very same process by which it would deduce here

```
int main() {
   auto& l = lambda;
}
```

That `l` is const reference.